# How can I remove or override any CSS from WordPress admin Panels additional CSS page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to apply a CSS on a WordPress site's page. But it is not applying because it seems that it is already overridden by this CSS
[image]

Is there anyway I can remove this CSS from WordPress Admin Panels additional CSS page? Please help me. TIA.

Comment: Have you tried `!important`?

Comment: @Ouroborus I have tried important but its not working. As you can see in the image that this already existing CSS also have important. I think that's why its not working. I want to remove this CSS. is there any way?

Comment: No, I don't see that. None of the CSS in the screenshot uses `!important`.

Comment: I am really sorry. Although there is no !important., My CSS is not working after adding !important.

Comment: Looks more like a theme issue, have you created a child theme for this?

Comment: Yes! I am using child them. The main theme is Kunstwerk.

Comment: You don't have a style to override that #main .products-holder .products. You need that to make changes, the ID per CSS is very strong in the global cascade so your classes below won't be strong enough to override as they deal more with not pseudos of that class combo.

Comment: But I am unable to find that CSS anywhere in my code. Its only visible from the browsers inspect section. I guess there is no option for removing the CSS?

Comment: That's exactly right it's not in your code, that's why you have to add it. :)

#main .products-holder .products {
// your overriding styles here in styles.css
}

Comment: @NathanielFlick, I have tried this with !important. But not working.

Comment: As long as your child theme stylesheet is last you shouldn't have to use important and it will work. Perhaps screenshot the source so we can see the load order of your css.